# Issue when trying to export spring bean as OSGI service

Tags: spring, osgi, osgi-bundle, spring-bean

I wanted to export a bean as a OSGi service , so that this can be used in another bundle. But I get the below error. Please help.

SEVERE: Unable to create application context for [com.abc.test.impl], unsatisfied dependencies: Dependency on [(objectClass=com.abc.platform.test.manager.ITestManager)] (from bean [&testManager]) 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Application context initialization for 'com.xyz.test.impl' has timed out waiting for (objectClass=com.abc.test.manager.ITestManager)

The code is given below.

Bundle 1 (com.abc.test.impl) : 
Bean declaration -

```
<bean id="testManagerTarget" class="com.abc.platform.test.TestManager">  
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>  
</bean>  

<bean id="testManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">  
       <property name="transactionManager">  
              <ref bean="transactionManager" />  
       </property>  
       <property name="target">  
              <ref bean="testManagerTarget" />  
       </property>  
       <property name="transactionAttributes">  
              <props>  
                     <prop key="store">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>  
              </props>  
       </property>  
</bean>
```

Declaring bean as OSGI service -

```
 Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped
<osgi:service id="testManagerService" ref="testManager" interface="com.abc.platform.test.manager.ITestManager" />
```

Bundle 2 (com.xyz.test.impl):

```
<osgi:reference id="testManager" interface="com.abc.platform.test.manager.ITestManager" />
```

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks 
Soniya

Comment: The first bundle is not actually exporting the service. There is probably something wrong with the way it has been constructed, e.g. maybe blueprint.xml in the wrong place, or not declared in the manifest?

Comment: What OSGi enviorment are you using? Do you use Blueprint? Or Spring DM? Where did you put your configuration XML's? And how are they named? And are you sure the `testManager` got exported properly?

Comment: NeilBartlett and Roadrunner Yes you both are right. The beans were not exported correctly.I am really not sure what was the issue.But I tried again and I was successfully able to export the beans as osgi:service and use them. Thanks a ton!!